# NSDictionaryController and image

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsimagecell

I am referring to [this example code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DictionaryController/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004522). I am trying to display image in the first column at where lastName is displaying, but unfortunately I can't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in two ways-

1. The data-source - peopleList array contains dictionary which does not have any NSImage object. You can try adding a NSImage object to the dictionary and then display it through  bindings.
2. You can use - tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row: in NSTableViewDelegate and for the lastName tablecolumn identifier, set appropriate image to the cell.

Also, since you are a beginner, I would like to refer a simpler example to you :  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9999259/SimpleTable.zip

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks for helping Miraaj.. And yes i am new to this.. so can u please explain these two ways in detail via some code..? that would be very big help for me..!!